# Formatting Fonts and Alignment

Tags: python-2.7, openpyxl

I'm trying to add fonts and alignment to an Excel worksheet using Python 2.7 and OpenPyXL 2.4.5.   I'm getting the following error, but I don't understand why.  Can anyone explain this to me?  From my testing, it's related to me setting the font (incorrectly?), and not the actual save.

```
C:\Scripts\Stack_Overflow>xlsx_font_and_alignment.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Scripts\Stack_Overflow\xlsx_font_and_alignment.py", line 61, in <modu
le>
    main()
  File "C:\Scripts\Stack_Overflow\xlsx_font_and_alignment.py", line 59, in main
    report_wb.save(report_fname)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 342, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 266, in save_workbook
    writer.save(filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 248, in save
    self.write_data()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 90, in write_data
    stylesheet = write_stylesheet(self.workbook)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 199, in write_style
sheet
    stylesheet.fonts = wb._fonts
  File "C:\Python27\lib\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py", line 27, in __set__
    seq = [_convert(self.expected_type, value) for value in seq]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 59, in _convert
    raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))
TypeError: expected <class 'openpyxl.styles.fonts.Font'>
```

Here's my code.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment, Font
import os.path
def xlsx_font_and_alignment(ws_to_format, x_axis, y_axis):
    """ Format Excel worksheet font and alignment and return the worksheet. """
    report_font = Font(name='Courier New',
                       size=10, \
                       bold=False, \
                       italic=False, \
                       vertAlign=None, \
                       underline='none', \
                       strike=False, \
                       color='FF000000')
    header_font = Font(name='Courier New', \
                       size=10, \
                       bold=True, \
                       italic=False, \
                       vertAlign=None, \
                       underline='none', \
                       strike=False, \
                       color='FF000000')
    report_alignment = Alignment(horizontal='left', \
                                 indent=1, \
                                 vertical='center', \
                                 wrap_text=True)
    header_alignment = Alignment(horizontal='left', \
                                 indent=2, \
                                 vertical='center', \
                                 wrap_text=True)
    if x_axis == 1:
        if ws_to_format.cell(row=1, column=y_axis).value:
            ws_to_format.cell(row=1, column=y_axis).font = header_font
            ws_to_format.cell(row=1, column=y_axis).font = header_alignment
    if x_axis != 1:
        if ws_to_format.cell(row=x_axis, column=y_axis).value:
            ws_to_format.cell(row=x_axis, column=y_axis).font = report_font
            ws_to_format.cell(row=x_axis, column=y_axis).alignment = report_alignment
    return ws_to_format
def main():
    """ Use OpenPyXL to format a XLSX. """
    csv_list = [['Endpoint ID', 'Occurred At', 'Status', 'Message'],
                ['Foo EP', '2017-04-20T04:10:11', 'Foo Status', 'Foo Message'],
                ['Foo EP', '2017-04-20T04:10:11', 'Foo Status', 'Foo Message'],
                ['Foo EP', '2017-04-20T03:15:01', 'Foo Status', 'Foo Message'],
                ['Foo EP', '2017-04-20T03:15:01', 'Foo Status', 'Foo Message'],
                ['Foo EP', '2017-04-19T20:00:12', 'Foo Status', 'Foo Message']]
    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    report_fname = path + "\\" + "Test_Report_" + ".xlsx"
    report_wb = Workbook()
    report_wb.create_sheet("Font Test")
    ws_to_format = report_wb.get_sheet_by_name("Font Test")
    for row in csv_list:
        ws_to_format.append(row)
    row_count = ws_to_format.max_row
    column_count = ws_to_format.max_column
    for y_axis in range(1, column_count+1):
        for x_axis in range(1, row_count+1):
            ws_to_format = xlsx_font_and_alignment(ws_to_format, x_axis, y_axis)
    report_wb.save(report_fname)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The odd thing is that I don't get the error when I attempt to change the fonts and alignment in the following manner.   However, I'd like to be able to use something similar to the above to avoid itterating through the entire data set when formatting.

```
def xlsx_font_and_alignment(ws_to_format):
    """ Format Excel worksheet font and alignment and return the worksheet. """
    report_font = Font(name='Courier New',
                       size=10, \
                       bold=False, \
                       italic=False, \
                       vertAlign=None, \
                       underline='none', \
                       strike=False, \
                       color='FF000000')
    header_font = Font(name='Courier New', \
                       size=10, \
                       bold=True, \
                       italic=False, \
                       vertAlign=None, \
                       underline='none', \
                       strike=False, \
                       color='FF000000')
    report_alignment = Alignment(horizontal='left', \
                                 indent=1, \
                                 vertical='center', \
                                 wrap_text=True)
    header_alignment = Alignment(horizontal='left', \
                                 indent=2, \
                                 vertical='center', \
                                 wrap_text=True)
    row_count = ws_to_format.max_row
    column_count = ws_to_format.max_column
    for y_axis in range(1, column_count+1):
        for x_axis in range(1, row_count+1):
            if ws_to_format.cell(row=x_axis, column=y_axis).value:
                ws_to_format.cell(row=x_axis, column=y_axis).font = report_font
                ws_to_format.cell(row=x_axis, column=y_axis).alignment = report_alignment
    for y_axis in range(1, column_count+1):
        ws_to_format.cell(row=1, column=y_axis).font = header_font
        ws_to_format.cell(row=1, column=y_axis).alignment = header_alignment
    return ws_to_format
```

Comment: Looks like you're working against the API. Your code will be easier to understand if you stick with it.

Comment: @CharlieClark -- Can you expand upon your statement?  In what ways am I working against the API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is you are setting the font attribute of the cell to an alignment object.

In this section of your code you have this.

```
if x_axis == 1:
    if ws_to_format.cell(row=1, column=y_axis).value:
        ws_to_format.cell(row=1, column=y_axis).font = header_font
        ws_to_format.cell(row=1, column=y_axis).font = header_alignment
```

Notice in the last line of this section you have .....**font** = header_**alignment**

Try changing that to alignment and see if it works for you

```
if x_axis == 1:
    if ws_to_format.cell(row=1, column=y_axis).value:
        ws_to_format.cell(row=1, column=y_axis).font = header_font
        ws_to_format.cell(row=1, column=y_axis).alignment = header_alignment
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that.  Thanks for pointing it out.  By the way, how do I mark your answer as correct?

Comment: Your welcome. Click the green check mark to the left of the answer to mark it answered.